# jQuery .on() not binding event-handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to attach an event handler to every row in a dynamically-changing table with no success (using jQuery version 1.11.0) 
* Edit: As many have pointed out, '**hover**' is depricated, but my problem also exists with other handlers*

```
$('#tableBody tbody').on('hover', 'tr', function() {
    alert('hovering on a row');
});
```

The above code is pretty much identical to the jQuery documentation- http://api.jquery.com/on/, and I've tried other variations, like

```
$(document).on('hover', '.tableRow', function(){...});
```

The event handler just isn't getting added. 
I should note that the table's contents are retrieved though AJAX and then displayed, which is why I'm using the .on() method.

Comment: exists `on` on v1.11? Did u mean 1.11.0? 1.11 is very old

Comment: If you search for `hover` on that page, you will see *"Deprecated in jQuery 1.8, removed in 1.9: The name "hover" used as a shorthand for the string "mouseenter mouseleave"."*

Comment: @Adrian Preuss, yes, I meant 1.11.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Passing `'hover'` as a string to `.on()` is no longer supported (removed in v1.9 as mentioned under the "Additional Notes" in the [`.on()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)). The equivalent is to use `'mouseenter mouseleave'` instead, or if you just want to do something when the mouse enters the element(s) in question try:

```
$('#tableBody tbody').on('mouseenter', 'tr', function() {
```

Note that the `#tableBody` element would need to exist at the time that that runs, so you'd need to include that either in a document ready handler or in a script element at the end of the body.

And the id `'tableBody'` sounds like it is assigned to the `<tbody>` element, which doesn't make sense when your selector also includes `tbody` as a child of `#tableBody`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, but I've also tried 'mouseenter' as well as other events, like 'click' with no success

Comment: If you can't get _any_ event to bind to your dynamic elements that's a whole nother problem. Does the `#tableBody` element exist at the time you run the `.on()` code? (It would need to.)

Comment: Yes, it does exist right when the page is loaded. And like I mentioned, it also won't work with $(document).on(...)

Comment: And the `#tableBody` element is the `<table>` element itself, not the `<tbody>` element? And only the rows are added/changed dynamically, the `<table>` element itself isn't replaced? Here's a demo where it _does_ work: http://jsfiddle.net/LjQqd/

Comment: That was it! '#tableBody' was assigned to the <tbody>, not the <table>. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

'mouseenter' event should work just fine.

```
$('#myTable tbody').on('mouseenter', 'tr', function() {
    alert('hovering on a row');
});
```

This is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XA78C/)